Как скрыть клавиатуру после сообщения тг бот
Есть бот на aiogram3, в нём используется ввод с клавиатуры иногда. Вот вопрос, как скрыть клавиатуру на телефоне после отправки сообщения?

В документации aiogram3 по ссылке описано единоразовое использование клавиатуры, через изменение параметра класса aiogram.types.reply_keyboard_markup.ReplyKeyboardMarkup one_time_keyboard на true. После ввода клавиатура уберётся с экрана пользователя, но будет доступна при следующем вызове.

Это для reply кнопок, а мне надо что бы убиралась клавиатура экранна телефоне
